# ASCII art printing message on shell opening (bash) (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, string, bash, echo

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 to try Linux. I saw a terminal that look really cool with some message printed each time it is opened. I have been tinkering around with `.bashrc` file to replicate that but each time I try to print the pattern with echo command, some whitespaces appear in between ruining the pattern's symmetry. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the whitespace is all spaces and not tabs?  Tabs can be rendered with different widths in different contexts.

Comment: yes checked that, it's all whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the character `\` is not in the output (that is why lines are not equal). The `\` tells the interpreter to escape the character that follow. To print correctly your banner you must write a `\` in front of each `\` (like `\\`). That will actually inform the interpreter to print  the `\`.

```
read -d '' String <<"EOF"
 /*** ===================================================================== ***/
  *                           _.-..                                           *
  *                           ,'9 )\\)`-.,.--.                                 *
  *                           `-.|           `.                               *
  *                              \\,      ,    \\)                              *
  *                               `.  )._\\   (\\                               *
  *                                |//   `-,//                                *
  *                                ]||    //"                                 *
  **                               ""    ""                                  **
 /*** ===================================================================== ***/
EOF

echo "$String"
```

For example, escaping `n` (`\n`) means "new line".

Some [readings about escaping char](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Another way is by adding the `r` option to `read`

```
read -rd ... etc etc ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to just print a super complex string having ' and / and \ etc.. without all these pre-formatting to be done ex:- like echo $X

Comment: You have to work on the read function, by adding a `r` option.

Comment: read -r worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Size of each character is defined by your font, which is set in your terminal emulator. Go to settings and choose something monospaced in settings.

Comment: Changing to monospace font didn't help.